# Whole 2 line code, producing a bug (infix operator)

Tags: functions, bugs, operators, boxes

Copy the following code, and create new 0 byte file, and paste the code and save it to TEST.nb

```
Notebook[{
Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"a", "\[CircleMinus]", "b", "\[CircleMinus]", "c", "\[CircleMinus]", 
  "d"}]], "Input",
 CellLabel->"In[1]:=",ExpressionUUID->"dd7bd8a7-440c-445a-8fd1-5a45ab09d900"],

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"a", "\[CircleMinus]", 
  RowBox[{"b", "\[CircleMinus]", 
   RowBox[{"c", "\[CircleMinus]", "d"}]}]}]], "Input",
 CellLabel->"In[2]:=",ExpressionUUID->"765feda5-1dfc-460d-9708-11c014613ad9"]
},
WindowSize->{937, 778},
WindowMargins->{{221, Automatic}, {Automatic, 21}},
FrontEndVersion->"11.3 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 6, 2018)",
StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"
]
```

[image]

Execute the TEST.nb, then you will see ***pic1.***

After running (=produce output) 1st input, you will see ***pic2***.

After running 2nd input, you will see ***pic 3***.

Surprisingly, the output is different from that of pic2!

You see parentheses not seen in pic 2.

Run 1st input again, and 2nd input again, see ***pic 4***.

There are no changes for each input.

Now select the last character of the 2nd input code, see ***pic 5***.

You see 'd' is highlightened with blue color.

Press 'd' of your keyboard, see ***pic 6***.

You might think this procedure is completely meaningless.
(select 'd' and press 'd' of the keyboard? that surely is a nothing!)

Run 2nd input again, see ***pic 7***.

Surprisingly, the output has changed now!
Now the output for 2nd input is the same as that of 1st input.

Can you explain this phenomenon? a bug ?

I got the code while creating custom operators.

Comment: This looks like a good write up to send to wolfram support.